# How do I spawn repeatedly object whot 0.1 seconds between them?

Tags: unity-game-engine, wait

I want to spawn a 100 object whit 0.1 seconds in between.
I have this but they still spawn all at once.

```cs
private float timer = 0.0f;
bool goSpawn = false;
private void Update()
{
    if (goSpawn)
    {
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
public void spawnAnimals()
{
    goSpawn = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100;)
    {
        if (timer > 2f)
        {
            RndSpawnPos = new Vector3(Random.Range(3.30f, 5.70f), 0.78f, Random.Range(-3.00f, 3.01f));
            Instantiate(animal, RndSpawnPos, Quaternion.identity);
            i++;
            timer = 0.0f;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `IEnumerator`. I put an example to solve the problem:

```cs
public void Start() => StartCoroutine(SpawnObject(100, .1f));

public IEnumerator SpawnObject(int count, float intervalTime)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        Instantiate(" something in here...");
        
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(intervalTime);
    }
}
```